# CW complex with one 0-cell

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Is there any example for CW complex with one 0-cell that is not connected?I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with a connected singleton and every next cell we attach keeps a connected space connected. So by induction the resulting space is connected.